# convert array into two different string php

Tags: php

I have an array with following elements:

```
$arr = array(
    'nick' => "blabla",
    'pass => "blabla2"'
);
```

I would like to convert it somehow to strings, the first string would be the value of `nick` - "blabla", the second string would be the value of `pass` - "blabla2"

Thank you.

Comment: What did you tried ? And what is the problem here ?

Comment: "blabla" is a string, just pass it to a variable. $variable = $array['nick']

Comment: Hmmm... maybe `$str1 = $arr['nick']; $str2 = $arr['pass']` ?)

Comment: `$myArray=['nick' => "blabla" , 'pass' => "blabla2"]; $string_one = $myArray['nick'];$string_two= $myArray['pass']; `

Comment: Whats wrong with leaving them as an array - is it really that much easier to use `$nick` than `$array['nick']`

Comment: @NigelRen nick should always be allowed to be free rather than putting him in a box! :-)

Comment: @Nick not is he nicks something. Then he should be both enclosed and put in a box!

Comment: @Andreas it was probably mistaken identity with mick! it's easy enough to do...

Comment: I am adamantly opposed to putting micks or nicks in boxes.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to convert elements of the array to separate string variables you can use [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function to import elements from an array to variables. For example:

```
$arr =  array(
   'nick' => "blabla",
   'pass' => "blabla2"
);

extract($arr);

echo $nick, ' ', $pass;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr =  [
   'nick' => "blabla",
   'pass' => "blabla2"
];

$string_one=$arr['nick'];
$string_two=$arr['pass'];
```